# R functions only return empty lists

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to use the functions readHTMLTable and readHTMLList on the website shown in the code below. These functions have generally worked for me in the past, but in both cases only empty lists are returned.

Thoughts?

```
basketball.url <- paste("http://stats.statbroadcast.com/broadcast/?id=186227")
library(XML)
basketball.webpage <- htmlParse(basketball.url)
basketball <- readHTMLTable(basketball.webpage)
basketball2 <- readHTMLList(basketball.webpage)
```

Comment: Not your problem, but I don't think you need `paste`. Just use `basketball.url <- "http://stats.statbroadcast.com/broadcast/?id=186227"`

Comment: If the data is being loaded with JavaScript, you'd need to use a scraper that can run it. The HTML doesn't contain the data until after the JavaScript is run.